# Removing package in Anaconda

Tags: anaconda

I have installed a package using anaconda and pip and then removed the package using pip. When i uninstalled using pip in `cmd` it says uninstalled. So now i have too remove this package from anaconda.
[image]

As you can see from the picture above `yfinance` shows it is installed. However when i try to run the command: `conda remove yfinance` it says package not found:

[image]

How can i remove this package? Because i need to install a fork of this package.

[image]

--**Edit**:--
I tried to install this package but i am getting an error:
[image]

Thus i cannot uninstall it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to install the package anaconda, and then to try uninstall again.

```
conda install yfinance

conda remove yfinance
```

I hope this helps.

**EDIT**

You can also delete the directory of the package, as you pointed out. But make sure you are in the correct one! This seems to be in your root directory of anaconda, as you use the *base* environment. In my case, this would be

```
/home/user/anaconda3
```

You may want to use a search tool to find the correct folder. This might be

```
/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/yfinance
```

Comment: I am not able to install this package and getting an error. Can i not just go to the directory were the file is located and remove it there or would that break things?

Comment: Of course you can! But make sure you are in the correct directory. This should be in a folder that is called `base`, as you seem to work in your base environment. I have edited my anser to include this option.

Comment: Ignore my last answer please. I just realized that you work in your `base` environment, which is not an environment you have created! The correct place is therefor the root directory of you anaconda installation.

Comment: This is not making sense i am at the root folder where all the packages are install and i am not able to find `yfinance` there. I know i am at the root because i used `where anaconda` command

Comment: This is interesting. Can you please try to run `conda clean`? You may want to try to install the package as described above again.

Comment: I have updated my answer again, with a possible location of the package.

Comment: For some reason even though the package is not found after running a scan of c:/ i am still able to use the package.